# How to include an independent variable as an input to a statistical model

Tags: independence, covariance-matrix, joint-distribution

I want to create a statistical model of the following model inputs $v_{in}$ and outputs $v_{out}$ that consist of continuous random variables. The final aim is to calculate the conditional distribution $p(v_{out}\mid v_{in})$.

$$v_{in} = \begin{bmatrix} d_{pre} \\ P_{sys} \end{bmatrix} \quad v_{out} = \begin{bmatrix} d_{post} \\ \varepsilon \end{bmatrix}$$

I have data for all variables except $d_{pre}$, and want to include it as an independent variable in the statistical model. This implies

$$
F(d_{pre}, P_{sys}) = F_{d_{pre}}(d_{pre}) F_{P_{sys}}(P_{sys}),
$$
where $F(d_{pre}, P_{sys})$ is the joint distribution of marginal distributions $F_{d_{pre}}(d_{pre})$ and $F_{d_{pre}}(d_{pre})$. The independence also implies 0 covariance between inputs, i.e.
$$
\begin{aligned}\textit{Cov}(d_{pre}, P_{sys}) = \mathbb{E}(d_{pre}, P_{sys}) - \mu_{d_{pre}} \mu_{ P_{sys}} \\ = (d_{pre})\mathbb{E}(P_{sys}) - \mu_{d_{pre}} \mu_{ P_{sys}} \ =0,  \end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mu$ the expected and mean values of the variables in the dataset.

Is there a closed form for the inclusion of a variable as an independent variable, or is the above sufficient to impose independence?  By closed form, I mean is there any other constraint I need to impose to ensure that $d_{pre}$ is independent of the other input variable?

P.S. I am an engineer new to statistics..